# Не загружается скрипт яндекс-карт версии 3.0-бета, ошибка 400

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

При попытке загрузить скрипт яндекс-карт версии 3.0-бета он не загружается, ошибка 400. В теге script атрибут src равен "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/3.0-beta/?apikey=<мой ключ>&lang=ru_RU".

Страницу запускаю локально: http://127.0.0.1:5500. При этом для этого же ключа для версии 2.1 скрипт загружается.

Как загрузить скрипт для яндекс-карт версии 3.0-beta?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы:

1. В настройках бесплатного ключа для API яндекс-карт в кабинете разработчика Яндекс в поле "Ограничение по HTTP Referer" указываем какое-нибудь доменное имя, например:
   "site.ru".
2. В операционной системе своего ПК в файл hosts указываем для введенного в п.1 доменного имени ip "127.0.0.1", например:
   "127.0.0.1 site.ru".
3. После запуска локального сервера, обращаемся к нему, указав в адресной строке браузера заданное в п.1 доменное имя и используя порт, на котором запущен локальный сервер, например:
   "http://site.ru:5500".